# Bulk Approval on sharepoint version control

Tags: approval, version

Is there any way of bulk approving all of the files in multiple folders in one sharepoint library?

My colleague has placed his cad drawings in multiple folders and i can bulk approve per folder but not for the entire library? For reference they uploaded 900+ documents into 60+ folders!

For those that cannot find the site manager content you can simply go to your site homepage and add **_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx** to the end of the URL in the address bar. you can then select all the files in a folder and click the actions button to approve all of them.

However i cannot see a way of expanding all the files in all of the folders to approve all 900 at the same time!

This is only an initial load kind of problem subsequent modifications to approve will be few and manageable one by one.

Thanks

Comment: could you do a workflow in Sharepoint Designer and use the: "set Approval Status field to 'Approved'?  I guess you would need to run it manually on each item though, unless you could do it using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a flat view which will essentially show you all files without folders.  Then you can easily bulk approve all of them.

Comment: Sounds like that would involve doing this: create/modify view, scroll down to the  Folder section, then select 'show all items without folders'.  This would assume that you can manually select 'Approve' in your approval column.